# Compile SFML 2.1 for Visual Studio Express 2013 Windows Desktop

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, compilation, linker, sfml

I am new to C++ programming, so I thought to get into it by getting familiar with SFML.
I downloaded Visual Studio 2013 Express Windows Desktop.

Then I realized that there is no SFML for VS2013.
So I have to compile/built it for me and I downloaded CMake.

When compiling it regarding some of the many tutorials on the internet, I get to the point, when I have to build in VS2013 with the "SFML_STATIC" flag.
Thus before, I build it successfully for the shared libs.

When I generate in CMake against the generator "Visual Studio 12 2013", it will create five projects:

- sfml-audio.vcxproj
- sfml-graphics.vcxproj
- sfml-network.vcxproj
- sfml-system.vcxproj
- sfml-window.vcxproj

It starts off with a problem that 4 of 5 projects are corrupt, so I have to manually fix the .vcxproj files.
After that I reload the projects and I start building the solution.

I do get linker errors, telling me he/she/it cannot find several files:
opengl32.lib;winmm.lib;gdi32.lib;ws2_32.lib;
and some SFML specific files.

I have found out that those files are in a location where in VS2013 the variable #(WindowsSdkDir) points to. But still those .dlls are note found, see
[image: Linker error after compiling with static flag]

I also have found that there are some issues with this for VS2013 targeted at MS.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Did anyone built it successfully?

Many thanks in advance. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I was able to use the unofficial nightly builds, http://sfml.my-gate.net/nightly/. Now it works for me. The nightly build are actually really up to date, also for VS2013.